# Unexpected implicit any type from union with generic type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to dynamically infer method parameters but for some reason I am getting an implicit any type inferred, even though I do see a valid method definition when I hover the execute method, it does work when I rename either method to something other than `execute` but I would rather keep them the same, how could I achieve this?

```js
type CommandBase<T extends BaseCommandInteraction> = ApplicationCommandData & {
  execute(interaction: T): unknown | Promise<unknown>
}

export type ContextMenuCommand = CommandBase<ContextMenuInteraction<"cached">> &
  (UserApplicationCommandData | MessageApplicationCommandData)

export type SlashCommand = CommandBase<CommandInteraction<"cached">> &
  ChatInputApplicationCommandData

type ExtraLegacyCommandData<TArgs> = {
  resolveArgs(args: Args, message: Message): TArgs
}

type LegacyCommand<TArgs> = {
  type: "LEGACY"
  name: string
  description: string
  execute(message: Message, args: TArgs): unknown | Promise<unknown>
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-types
} & (TArgs extends void ? {} : ExtraLegacyCommandData<TArgs>)

export type Command<TArgs> =
  | ContextMenuCommand
  | SlashCommand
  | LegacyCommand<TArgs>

export function createCommand<TArgs = void>(command: Command<TArgs>) {
  return command
}

export default createCommand({
  type: "LEGACY",
  name: "",
  description: "",
  execute(message) {
    // Type signature shows `execute(message: Message<boolean>, args: void): unknown`
    // But `Parameter 'message' implicitly has an 'any' type.`
  },
})
```

[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBDAnmApnA3gKDnAgmMAG2AGMBDGYCAOwGEIQQzqATAEQrIBps4AhMgGcU9RsxYBJajBRQyJSjR45aACwpSwAVxj4ipClToMmrDjG69RpydNnzF1ZXHp2AHjACyKalqky5BSNnb0FBMgBzFBCUMMiUPWJyR2txc0scAFVhKESDFJM0zh4AXzgAMygGOAAiFmBBEmgWADoAK0EazFBIWARkNHQ8KAjBODLK6prCFDctKBQuzFne+CRUF0LWAWEAHgAVOFmZVjGdkS3bAIcjAD44AF5ePOSjVLNOOAAyDF4cWZQJB0KAAFMA7IFHAAuOD7ACUMK01AA1tQIAB3ahwAA+cAAClUQA0ULskaiMdRbrwSphlm5Vv0Nq4ZB5vL53ixHpsxNshCTmcc2X4ITcaLsauQSKoUCward7l9eCDsrIXoYaBz0ji4KFwlE1QUeexOHDaStoGsBnAAMqEISqDlcjnnXYc-z2IJiiXyaWy+XfKzqGCaHQGt6XdK09ZoAAyKAi8kQHIA6sAYKpcCNBASIGBBAdM6N7g9fjgFoIIIQAG4JLMgshZmGFwRcOAgWJ6lAw3XxBGw5uYGmYaNwOMJkhJy4FrNcqsQYAsYulxld2oxgCiAHFcLQAJpdHDUMjtmGCGBQcERXgsWIkC9gaFwM8X6hX-5uQHAkHtuJRbsd+JWwbUYYX2Zs+zJNFMW1HMiT2SCKSpHAAHpkKOQRiGkABaepwgAIxmLDqGOLDMLQAABaNGnvGAsNiTCYGQvDmCwqjB2+OAQTAmdjh8FgxjnBc4AAfgwMoYTHRMUzTDMsxzPNpyLU06QZEcOUUsYS0ExdHl4XEBVZHwtA5PSbTtQQHUuUzJIndTuKLM16QtCokU9LE7xQCgLiNDTZ3nRcQSaI0YTs5tbjhZcFhgeZ3KsodzT6G9yjILRCHgDyvI5EEsBwaMYRqDdtz3GpnCPE9ahvIgIEQErr1vGijHy2qcCERBqBII4PyBGRvwAqIIqGVDOPbdMIBYCKAW60Ef07f9fxJPCIErTzKSAxs4G0iCUSg6heCGnADsOnAAD1hNpHAaRKZSgA)

Edit: I figured inference does work when I define both expected function parameters, I tried to avoid having to do that like this:

```js
type LegacyCommand<TArgs> = {
  type: "LEGACY"
  name: string
  description: string
  execute(
    message: Message,
    ...args: TArgs extends void ? [] : [TArgs]
  ): unknown | Promise<unknown>
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-types
} & (TArgs extends void ? {} : ExtraLegacyCommandData<TArgs>)
```

But this won't work either:

```
// (method) execute(message: Message<boolean>): unknown
async execute(message) { // Parameter 'message' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

Comment: This is pretty complicated and I'm not familiar with the `discord.js` library, but the parameter type seems to be inferred correctly if you write `export default createCommand<void>({ ... })` instead of `export default createCommand({ ... })`. It doesn't make any sense to me, because `void` is the inferred type for the generic parameter anyway, but for some reason unbeknown to me, it works, at least.

Comment: Thanks that does seem to work, I also cannot figure out why, I will try some more and leave this open for a possible explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my issue was related to https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#generic-type-parameters-are-implicitly-constrained-to-unknown, to fix it, I provided an explicit constraint to my function and slightly adjusted my execute method

```js
type LegacyCommand<TArgs> = {
  type: "LEGACY"
  name: string
  description: string
  execute: (
    message: Message,
    // Only exposing arguments when array of known type is passed as generic
    ...args: TArgs extends unknown[] ? [TArgs] : []
  ) => unknown | Promise<unknown>
  // Checking if tuple generic was passed in
} & (TArgs extends [unknown] ? ExtraLegacyCommandData<TArgs> : {})

// Explicit constraint
export function createCommand<TArgs extends unknown[] = []>(
  command: Command<TArgs>
) {
  return command
}
```